# ServiceStack OpenAPI TagAttribute

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-openapi

Does anyone know where ServiceStack is referencing `TagAttribute` from. According to ServiceStack's OpenAPI documentation a route can be marked as `[Tag("Core Requests")]` to categorize the routes but I cannot locate where `TagAttribute` is actually defined. I am using ServiceStack v4.5.8.

http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Tag]` attribute was [added in the latest v4.5.10 release](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.10#open-api) so you'll need to upgrade to **v4.5.10+** to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Still not sure what the problem with v4.5.10 is as after upgrading to this the whole SS API stops working. Can't get to any SS endpoint. Also swagger won't work.

Comment: @Mayank if you're using Signed DLLs you'll need to use the Myget release, it's a known issue were going to deploy a quick fix on NuGet today for

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the update. When do you think the update will be available today?

Comment: @Mayank v4.5.12 is now available on NuGet

Comment: New build fixed the issue, Thanks